# Custom Notificaton Sound from raw folder doesn't play always?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have implemented broadcast Receiver to Intercept incoming msgs and if certain text i am looking for is found out then play custom Notification from Receiver.

Notification is generated properly but Custom Notification sound which i have stored in **raw folder** doesn't play always.Here is my code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            icon = R.drawable.icon;
            tickertext = "msg received!!!";
            when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notif = new Notification(icon,tickertext,when);
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context,"AppName", sb.substring(0,12), contentIntent);
            notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //Do not clear the notification
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
            notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
            notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.Myapp/" + R.raw.customtone);// Sound

            manager.notify(1, notif);
    }
    else{
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.MyApp/" + R.raw.customtone);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
               .setTicker("msg received!!!")
               .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
               .setContentTitle("AppName")
               .setContentText(sb.substring(0, 12))
               .setVibrate(new long[] {1000,1000,1000,1000,1000})
               .setLights(Color.RED,0,1)
               .setSound(uri)
               .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
               .setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notif = builder.getNotification();

        manager.notify(1, notif);

    }
```

When msg comes customtone is heared in **postGingerBread devices** but not in **preGingerbread devices**

Is there any prob with notification.sound property in **preGingerBread devices**??

Also in **postGingerBread devices** customtone plays for few seconds then is overshawdowed by default msg ringtone i.e custom tone plays for 3 sec then sms tone starts playing.

Is there anyway i could overcome this?